# Reaching the content of a frame from a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, frames

I'm writing a Chrome Extension that changes calls to document.all so that it can be used in chrome.

However, the page consists of a script that writes a frameset using document.writeln.
The frameset consists of one frame "FrameMain".

I'm having difficulties getting a variable pointing to the document in FrameMain.

I think the problem is that the FrameMain isn't created when document_start in chrome and it's not loaded when document_end occurs.

I'm currently using document_end as a starting point for my script:

```
$('FrameMain').ready(function () {
    console.log("ready");
    console.log(parent.frames);
    console.log(parent.frames[0]);
});
```

The ready is printed when it seems the frame is loaded, it's not displayed immediately.
However, parent.frames returns a DOMWindow and parent.frames[0] is undefined.
**How can I get a reference to the frames content?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved it.**

```
$('FrameMain').ready(function () {
    console.log("ready");

    $($("frame[name = 'FrameMain']")[0].contentDocument).find("body").append("<h1>Hello frame</h1>");

});
```

Using the **frame** selector and **contentDocument** was the key.

:)